# Ahoy Ruby on Rails- join tables (Visit and Event)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, ahoy

I am using [Ahoy](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy) for tracking in my web app. I find events with this:

```
@events = Ahoy::Event.where_properties(title: params[:token])
```

and I want to get all Visits having visit ID that the above relation, @events, has.

I can join the two tables using `Visit.joins(:ahoy_events) but`  `Visit.joins(:@events)` gives an error, as expected. How do I do this?

Comment: `Visit.where(ahoy_events: @events)` ??

Comment: Since we're only querying by ID, there's no need to even `join` here.

Comment: @TomLord that gives "PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column visits.visit_id does not exist".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. Variables are not allowed in a joins() query, hence I used this

```
def show
    @events = Ahoy::Event.where_properties(title: params[:token])
    @visits = Visit.joins(:ahoy_events).where(:ahoy_events=>{:properties => {title: params[:token]}})
end
```

And it seems to be working.